# Wait for complete deletion of a DynamoDB table using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I need to delete a dynamodb table, and wait until it is completely removed. How can I check this?
boto3 api expose a method `get_waiter` to wait for certain events, but it is not well documented. Can I use it for this purpose? Which would be the event name, or maybe handle a ResourceNotFoundException

```
# Wait until the table exists.
table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='TableName')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After `delete_table` API, call `table_not_exists` waiter. This waits until the specified table returns 404.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
client.delete_table(TableName='foo')
waiter = client.get_waiter('table_not_exists')
waiter.wait(TableName='foo')
print ("table deleted")
```

For `create_table` API, call `table_exists` waiter. This waits until the specified table gets active.

Answer (score 9):

Without waiter,Now we can use wait_until_not_exists function like below example

```
table = dynamoResources.Table(table_name)
table.delete()
table.wait_until_not_exists()
```

Comment: for those that come across this, there is also a wait_until_exists if you need to wait for the table creation.

Comment: This seems cleaner than the accepted answer, especially if you already have the dynamodb Table defined as a variable. Possibly reconsider @Yasel?